# Can't set up beep sound in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set up the beep sound in my React.js application. I follow [this article](https://alligator.io/react/adding-sound-to-your-react-apps/), but it failed to get sound although I click the button.

```
import UIfx from "uifx";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const mp3file = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/sound/alert.mp3`;
    const sound = new UIfx({ asset: mp3file });
    sound.setVolume(0.8);
    console.log("sound", sound);
    return() {
        <button onClick={sound.play}>Signup</button>
    }
  }
}
```

The sound show like this:

```
UIfx {file: {…}, volume: 0.8, throttleMs: 0, play: ƒ, setVolume: ƒ, …}
play: ƒ (volume)
setVolume: ƒ (volume)
file: {asset: "/assets/sound/alert.mp3"}
volume: 0.8
throttleMs: 0
validateVolume: ƒ validateVolume(volume)
__proto__: Object
```

I have an error below:

> Uncaught Error: "Volume" must be an number between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.

First one is the UIFx constructor not accepting your object, you should do `new UIFx(mp3file)` instead.

Second one is with the `onClick={sound.play}` - `this` will be set to the element reference and will cause issues, what you should do is `onClick={() => sound.play()}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, this is a subtle one!

Notice that the logged `sound` object suggests that the `play` function takes a parameter named `volume`: `play: ƒ (volume)`. Remember that the [`onClick`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) passes an event as a parameter. So since the play function is passed directly, it's actually equivalent to `onClick={e => sound.play(e)}`!

Try the following:

```
return() {
  <button onClick={() => sound.play()}>Signup</button>
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the only problem with the code, I have created a React project just to test it out of sheer curiosity and the UIFx constructor is being called in an incorrect manner as well. Your answer is still partially correct, though.

Comment: Yup, just noticed your answer! Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a simple way to do a beep sound and happy to share my findings. I find **new AudioContext** light-weight. [Mozilla **AudioContext**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext). Reference: [ourcodeworld](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1627/how-to-easily-generate-a-beep-notification-sound-with-javascript). For me, this worked:

```
const addToCart = () => {
 function beep(duration, frequency, volume) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Set default duration if not provided
    duration = duration || 200;
    frequency = frequency || 440;
    volume = volume || 100;
        
     try {
      let oscillatorNode = myAudioContext.createOscillator();
      let gainNode = myAudioContext.createGain();
      oscillatorNode.connect(gainNode);
        
      // Set the oscillator frequency in hertz
      oscillatorNode.frequency.value = frequency;
        
      // Set the type of oscillator
      oscillatorNode.type = "square";
      gainNode.connect(myAudioContext.destination);
        
      // Set the gain to the volume
      gainNode.gain.value = volume * 0.01;
        
      // Start audio with the desired duration
      oscillatorNode.start(myAudioContext.currentTime);
      oscillatorNode.stop(myAudioContext.currentTime + duration * 0.001);
        
      // Resolve the promise when the sound is finished
      oscillatorNode.onended = () => {
        resolve();
        };
     } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
            
  });
 }
}
```

When you call the beep function like , you will have a "native beep sound" - correct me if am wrong.

```
beep(
        // Set the duration to 0.2 second (200 milliseconds)
        200,
        // Set the frequency of the note to A4 (440 Hz)
        440,
        // Set the volume of the beep to 100%
        100
      );
```